# Do the words "want" and "won't" sound the same?

Tags: pronunciation

Do the words "**want**" and "**won't**" (will not) sound the same? (and then the meaning understandable according to the context)

Here is the explanation (with the pronunciation sounds) on the difference between **want** and **won't**.

1) [Q&A: "WON'T" and "WANT" pronunciation/difference
-YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PuzmXNhdTao)

2) [American English: Want vs Won't
-YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iQBYfcALPzw)

Comment: Additional information needs to be added that describes why you believe (or don't believe) that they sound the same.

Comment: Done. As it's possible to see in my answer the difference now is clear to me since I saw the explanations on YouTube.

Comment: Most questioners are non-native speakers; that's not new information. If you mentioned what language you speak natively, or what English accent you hear most, that would help.

Answer (score 5):

All such questions will depend on the accent that the speaker has. In my own speech (I live in New York City) the two words do not sound the same. There are some accents in which they sound the same, or, at least, very similar.

However, the context will nearly always make it clear.  For these two words in particular, the grammar will usually make it clear:

I want NOUN  and I want TO VERB are two common usages of want.  But neither is grammatical with won't substituted.

On the other hand:

I won't VERB is very common and is not grammatical with want substituted.

E.g.
"I want to eat" is fine; "I won't eat" is also fine. But "I want eat" is not and "I won't to eat" is also not correct.

Comment: Sorry, but "I want eat" is not "good"? Perhaps one might say grammatical.